# Example using $\bigcap$-Notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

**Defintion:**

Suppose $I$ is a set and for every $i\in I$ there is a set $M_i$. Then the infinitary intersection is defined as follows:
$$
\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i:=\{x :x\in M_i \text{ for every } i\in I\}
$$

I tried constructing a simple example to visualize the definition. Hence let $I:=\{1,2,3\}$ and for every $i\in I$ there is a set $M_i$, so all in all we have $M_1, M_2, M_3$. Would $\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i=M_1\cap M_2 \cap M_3$?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: By the way, please never use $\bigcap_{i\in I}$ with $I=\emptyset$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen A mathematical analog to nitroglycerin: handle with *great* care.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

Try to imagine what is $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: hmm, no idea... ?

Comment: Draw a picture (one-dimensional).

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Well, which $x$ satisfy $-\frac{1}{n}<x<1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: I believe $0\leq x<1$

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Why should 1 not be included?

Comment: Sorry, $1$ is included. It's a typo.

Comment: Then prove this. Of course, every $x\in[0,1]$ is in this intersection. Then the converse inclusion. Take any $x$ in the intersection. Since $-\frac{1}{n}<x< 1+\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$, then, passing with $n$ to infinity, we get $0\le x\le 1$ (remember that in the limit only the weak inequality is preserved). Then the intersection in question is exactly $[0,1]$.